# How do I open google cloud shell in Mac?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk

I have installed Google cloud SDK following the documentation but can not use Shell

I have tried following different commands but shell is not opening

Answer (score 1):

To install the Google Cloud CLI

This quickstart guides you through installing and initializing the Google Cloud CLI and running a few core gcloud CLI commands.

**Before you begin**
In the Google Cloud console, on the project selector page, select or create a Google Cloud project.

****Note:**** If you don't plan to keep the resources that you create in this procedure, create a project instead of selecting an existing project. After you finish these steps, you can delete the project, removing all resources associated with the project.

2. Make sure that billing is enabled for your Cloud project. Learn how to check if billing is enabled on a project.

When you finish this tutorial, you can avoid continued billing by deleting the resources you created. For more information, see Clean up.

**Installing the latest gcloud CLI version (422.0.0)**
**Note:** Googlers on gLinux machines should use the Google-internal instructions instead of these instructions.

Note: If you are behind a proxy/firewall, see the proxy settings page for more information on installation.

1. Confirm that you have a supported version of Python:

-To check your current Python version, run python3 -V or python -V. Supported versions are Python 3 (3.5 to 3.9).
-For Cloud SDK release version 352.0.0 and above, the main install script offers to install CPython's Python 3.7 on Intel-based Macs.
-For more information on how to choose and configure your Python interpreter, refer to gcloud topic startup.
Download one of the following:
Note: To determine your machine hardware name, run uname -m from a command line.

Platform:
macOS 64-bit
(x86_64)

Package:
[google-cloud-cli-422.0.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-cli-422.0.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz)

Size
131.8 MB

SHA256 Checksum
907bd779fcfff992d85228d2de378a9822a08482776bd0d7758d4563102cc715

a. Extract the archive to any location on your file system (preferably your Home directory). On macOS, this can be achieved by opening the downloaded .tar.gz archive file in the preferred location.

-To replace an existing installation, remove the existing google-cloud-sdk directory and then extract the archive to the same location.

b.(Optional) Use the install script to add gcloud CLI tools to your PATH.You can also opt-in to command-completion for your shell, usage statistics collection, and install Python 3.7.

Run the script (from the root of the folder you extracted in the last step) using this command:

```
`./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`
```

This can also be done non-interactively (for example, using a script) by providing preferences as flags. To describe the available flags, run:

```
./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --help
```

To run the install script with screen reader mode on:

```
./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --screen-reader=true
```

Open a new terminal so that the changes take effect.
c. To initialize the gcloud CLI, run gcloud init:

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
```

d. Optional. Install additional components using the component manager.

**Optional: Install the latest Cloud Client Libraries**
-You can download Cloud Client Libraries for supported languages.

**Initializing the gcloud CLI**
Use the gcloud init command to perform several common gcloud CLI setup tasks. These include authorizing the gcloud CLI to access Google Cloud using your user account credentials and setting up the default configuration.

1. Initialize the gcloud CLI:

   gcloud init

**Note:** To prevent the command from launching a web browser, use gcloud init --console-only. To authorize without a web browser and non-interactively, create a service account with the appropriate scopes using the Google Cloud console and use gcloud auth activate-service-account with the corresponding JSON key file.

2. Accept the option to log in using your Google user account:

   To continue, you must log in. Would you like to log in (Y/n)? Y
3. In your browser, log in to your Google user account when prompted and click Allow to grant permission to access Google Cloud resources.
4. At the command prompt, select a Google Cloud project from the list of projects where you have Owner, Editor or Viewer permissions:

   Pick cloud project to use:
   [2](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#mac) [my-project-1]
   [2](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#mac) [my-project-2]

Please enter your numeric choice:

...
If you only have one project, gcloud init selects it for you.

If you have access to more than 200 projects, you will be prompted to enter a project id, create a new project, or list projects.

```
This account has a lot of projects! Listing them all can take a while.
 [2] Enter a project ID
 [2] Create a new project
 [3] List projects
Please enter your numeric choice:
```

**Note:** If you choose to create a project, you'll also need to enable billing on your project to use Google Cloud services.

5. If you have the Compute Engine API enabled, gcloud init allows you to choose a default Compute Engine zone:

   Which compute zone would you like to use as project default?
   [2](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#mac) [asia-east1-a]
   [2](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#mac) [asia-east1-b]
   ...
   [14] Do not use default zone
   Please enter your numeric choice:

gcloud init confirms that you have complete the setup steps successfully:

```
gcloud has now been configured!
You can use [gcloud config] to change more gcloud settings.

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

6. (Optional) To improve the screen reader experience, enable the accessibility/screen_reader property:

   gcloud config set accessibility/screen_reader true

For more details about the accessibility features that come with the gcloud CLI, see Enabling accessibility features guide.

**Running core commands**
Run core commands to view information about your gcloud CLI installation:

1. List accounts whose credentials are stored on the local system:

   gcloud auth list

The gcloud CLI displays a list of credentialed accounts:

```
Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE             ACCOUNT
*                  example-user-1@gmail.com
                   example-user-2@gmail.com
```

List the properties in your active gcloud CLI configuration:

```
gcloud config list

The gcloud CLI displays the list of properties:


[core]
account = example-user-1@gmail.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = example-project
```

3. View information about your gcloud CLI installation and the active configuration:

   gcloud info

The gcloud CLI displays a summary of information about your installation. This includes information about your system, the installed components, the active user account and current project, and the properties in the active configuration.

4. View information about gcloud commands and other topics:

   gcloud help

   For example, to view the help for gcloud compute instances create:

   gcloud help compute instances create

The gcloud CLI displays a help topic that contains a description of the command, a list of command flags and arguments, and examples of how to use the command.